# Canvas выделяется синим цветом при клике на Android

Tags: canvas, html5, android

Есть `canvas` элемент, на котором по координатам происходит обработка кликов.
В desktop-браузерах все работает отлично. Но решил проверить на планшете с android, и возникла проблема. Обработка событий происходит, в принципе, так же, как и на ПК, но при клике по `canvas`-у она как-бы покрывается голубоватым слоем на секунду. Можно ли как-то избежать этого?

**(UPD) Решено (может кому пригодится):**

для Opera Mobile использовал немного другой "костыль", но, как мне кажется, он будет работать для любых других браузеров Touch-устройств.

```
var el = document.getElementById("myid");
el.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /* выполняем необходимые действия */
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myWebView.setFocusable(false)
myWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false)
```

Comment: Это, я так понимаю, если приложение для android, а у меня это обычный сайт, с canvas'ом

Comment: попробуй -webkit-tap-highlight-color сделать transparent - говорят помогает... иногда...

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло, правда частично. В opera mobile это свойство не работает

Comment: мб outline none?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, пробовал, не то. outline: none по всей видимости работает только по фокусу, а на tap оно не работает.